# SELECT statement - ignore blank columns - joined tables

Tags: mysql, select, null

I'm joining 5 tables in vTiger in order to get all the info I need. However, there is an option that certain columns will be empty. In that case, my SELECT statement fails and I can't retrieve the rest of the results. How do I bypass this by adding a "Doesn't exist" default value if the column is blank?

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT
    vtiger_potentialscf.potentialid, 
    vtiger_potential.potentialname, 
    vtiger_contactdetails.accountid,
    vtiger_contactdetails.salutation,
    vtiger_contactdetails.firstname,
    vtiger_contactdetails.lastname,
    vtiger_account.accountname,
    vtiger_crmentity.smownerid, 
    vtiger_crmentity.crmid, 
    vtiger_crmentity.label, 
    vtiger_users.id,
    vtiger_users.email1 

    FROM vtiger_potential 

    INNER JOIN vtiger_potentialscf ON vtiger_potentialscf.potentialid = vtiger_potential.potentialid 
    INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_potential.potentialid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid 
    INNER JOIN vtiger_users ON vtiger_crmentity.smownerid = vtiger_users.id 
    INNER JOIN vtiger_contactdetails ON vtiger_potential.related_to = vtiger_contactdetails.accountid
    INNER JOIN vtiger_account ON vtiger_account.accountid = vtiger_potential.related_to
    WHERE `cf_919` = DATE(NOW())");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo $row['email1'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['smownerid'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['potentialname'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['accountid'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['salutation'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['firstname'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['lastname'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['accountname'] . "<br />";
```

In this case, I can have the `vtiger_contactdetails` empty. Any suggestion on how to get the rest of the content and just echo that these aren't available?

Comment: Use left join if it does not exist.

Comment: Can you advise on how?

Comment: In vtiger there will be lot of related tables where there would be no data. For example in some cases when you do not have a custom field for a module the scf suffixed tables will not have any data so doing inner join will return nothing. The only table where there will be a data related to the module is `vtiger_crmentity` so I would suggest to use `left join` instead of `INNER JOIN`. You can keep inner join to `vtiger_users` AND `vtiger_crmentity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use left join.
Have a look http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Thanks Abhik Chakraborty for a much better explanation in the comments.

Comment: That worked. Any tips on why the other one wasn't working? THANKS